# How to pay attention to the result of the server change the image

Tags: android

I want if the data is successfully stored on the server

Change the image Resource

I use this method but it does not work

what should I do

```
public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                            if (!obj.getBoolean("error")) {
                                //if there is a success
                                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                                View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.names, null, true);
                                ImageView imageViewStatus = (ImageView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.imageViewStatus);
                                imageViewStatus.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.success);
                            } else {
                                //
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: First you should check if the response is success, because the if statement isn't true, it never will change the image in the ImageView